# Elasticsearch aggregation on multi fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Here's an example of a document in my ES index:

```
{
  "src_ip": "192.168.1.1",
  "dst_ip": "192.168.1.2"
}
```

I want obtain the number of occurrences of ip in different documents(in field src_ip or dst_ip). What I would like to get as a result of the query is an aggregation like this:

```
[
  {"ip": "192.168.1.1", "count": 1"},
  {"ip": "192.168.1.2", "count": 1"}
]
```

Any idea about that? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), Where you will get the group counts.

```sh
POST index_name/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "src_ip_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "src_ip"
      }
    },
    "dst_ip_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dst_ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here i am assuming that the type of `src_ip` and `dst_ip` is [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html). If it's not, You need to store all value as keyword type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But the search returns two aggregation results, not one. Is possible to return one aggregation result, the aggregation key is all keywords in src_ip and dst_ip?

Comment: Yes it return two aggregations because you want group count on two individual field.   To convert in specific format, I would recommend to handle programmatically. But i hope you getting desire results. Let me know.

Comment: Mark it answered if its really helped you. So that others can take reference :)